# How to draw graph corresponding with its attributes in ggraph [R]

Tags: r, networking, igraph, ggraph

I am trying to draw following graph in `ggraph`.

[image: Desired graph]

`igraph` class object is obtained from a data frame below:

```
    edge <- data.frame(from=c(0,0,0,0,1,2,3),
                       to=c(0,1,2,3,0,0,0),
                       weight=c(1,3,1,1,3,1,1))
    node <- data.frame(id=c(0,1,2,3),
                       p=c(9,1,0,0),
                       w=c(0,2,0,0),
                       s=c(0,0,1,1),
                       size=c(9,3,1,1),
                       gr=c(0,1,1,2))

# Convert data frame into igraph class object
net <- graph_from_data_frame(d=edge,vertices=node,directed=TRUE)
```

However, when I draw the graph in the following scripts, it produces unexpected width of edges:

[image: Unexpected result]

```
## Set arrows
ar <- arrow(angle=30,length=unit(5,"mm"),ends="last",type="closed")
## Plot
ggraph(net,layout="graphopt") +
    ## Edges
    geom_edge_link(aes(width=weight,label=weight,
        start_cap=circle(node1.size+1,unit="native"),
        end_cap=circle(node2.size+1,unit="native")),
        angle_calc="along",force_flip=TRUE,
        label_dodge=unit(3.0,"mm"),label_push=unit(-0.4,"mm")) +
        ## Width scale
        scale_edge_width(range=c(0.2,4),breaks=c(1:10),name="Movements\nbetween zones") +
    ## Add arrows separately
    geom_edge_link(arrow=ar,aes(start_cap=circle(node1.size,unit="native"),
        end_cap=circle(node2.size,unit="native"))) +
    ## Nodes
    geom_node_circle(aes(r=size)) +
        ## Plot location id
        geom_node_label(aes(label=id),color="red",repel=TRUE,label.r=0.3,position="identity") +
        ## Plot work activity
        geom_node_text(aes(size=w),label="w",color="green",position="identity") +
        ## Plot school activity
        geom_node_text(aes(size=s),label="s",color="blue",position="identity") +
    ## Theme
    theme_graph() + coord_fixed()
```

There are some fundamental issues:

- <strike>Width of edges defined in `weight` does not correspond to node ID (`from/to` in `edge` and `name` in `node`). For instance, weight `3` is given to `0->1` and `1->0` in data frame but it appears between`0<->2` in the graph,</strike>
- <strike>An edge between `0<->1` gets inside of node `0` even if margins are set by `start_cap` and `end_cap`,</strike>
- `Weight` labels besides edges are not centralized (it is located near from node 0)
- Labels defined by `geom_node_label` overlaps nodes
- Size of labels inside nodes (`w` and `s`) seems okay, however they are not located as `dodge` (they are overlapped each other)

Issues other than the first point are just aesthetic issues but the first point is fatal error of the plot. I plotted it in `igraph` which gives appropriate relations between nodes and edges.

[image: Sample in igraph]

```
## Sample in igraph
E(net)$width <- E(net)$weight
plot(net,edge.width=E(net)$weight*5,vertex.size=V(net)$size*5,vertex.label.cex=3)
```

I highly appreciate your suggestions to solve any of above issues to obtain desired graph. I am new to use `ggraph` and found some solutions to obtain current graph, however I have been stacking to fix above issues at this moment.
(I prefer to use `ggraph` rather than `igraph` to control its appearance precisely)

========== UPDATE ==========  
Most of issues could be solved by the following scripts though it is very manual adjustment. One most important key is to remove loop edge between `0<->0` which caused inappropriate correspondence between label and actual width of edges.

```
## Load data frames as tbl_graph class
edge <- edge %>% mutate(from=from+1,to=to+1)
net <- tbl_graph(nodes=node,edges=edge,directed=TRUE)

## Set arrows
ar <- arrow(angle=30,length=unit(5,"mm"),ends="last",type="closed")
## Plot
ggraph(net,layout="graphopt") +
    ## Edges
    geom_edge_link(aes(start_cap=circle(log(node1.size)+2,unit="native"),
                       end_cap=circle(log(node2.size)+2,unit="native"),
                       width=weight,label=weight),
        position="identity",angle_calc="along",force_flip=TRUE,
        label_dodge=unit(4.0,"mm"),label_push=unit(-0.4,"mm")) +
        ## Width scale
        scale_edge_width(range=c(0.2,4),breaks=c(1:10),name="Movements\nbetween zones") +
    ## Add arrows separately
    geom_edge_link(arrow=ar,aes(start_cap=circle(log(node1.size)+1,unit="native"),
        end_cap=circle(log(node2.size)+1,unit="native"))) +
    ## Nodes
    geom_node_circle(aes(r=log(size)+1)) +
        ## Plot location id
        geom_node_label(aes(label=id,hjust=log(size+5),vjust=log(size+5)),repel=TRUE,
                        label.padding=unit(0.8,"mm"),label.r=unit(0.0,"mm"),label.size=0.1,size=3.5) +
        ## Plot work activity
        geom_node_text(aes(size=w,hjust=log(w)+0.6),label="w",color="red",position="identity",vjust=0.4) +
        ## Plot school activity
        geom_node_text(aes(size=s,hjust=-log(s)-0.3),label="s",color="blue",position="identity",vjust=0.4) +
        ## Size scale
        scale_size(range=c(0,5),breaks=c(1:100),name="Numberof\nActivities",
                   guide=guide_legend(override.aes=list(rep("a",100)))) +
        # scale_color() +
    ## Theme
    theme_graph() + coord_fixed()
```

[image]

However there are two remaining issues on legend:

- How can I replace overlapped "w" and "s" by other font, such as "a" (activity)?
- How can I add one more manual legend "Types of activity" shown in desired result?

**I posted it as a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51581399/manual-legend-in-ggraph-ggplot2-r)**